# Python how to split: 'A,B,"Don't split, please",D'?

Tags: python, regex, split

Is there a Pythonic way to split lines by comma where some of the lines have phrases that contain a comma that should not be used as a delimiter? For example, the "Split this?, No!" should be kept together in one piece even though it has a (non-delimiter) comma. Also, notice the unquoted 'D E F' which should be kept together. Also notice the empty field between F and G.

This:

```
    'A,B,"Split this?, No!",D E F,,G'
```

When split should yield:

```
    ['A', 'B', 'Split this? No!', 'D E F', '', 'G']
```

`shlex.split(line)` did not do it
`re.findall(r'(\w+|".*?")', a)` breaks up: D E F

Comment: You mean other than using `csv`?

Comment: Such a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import csv
>>> rows = csv.reader(['A,B,"Split this?, No!",D E F,G'])
>>> rows.next()
['A', 'B', 'Split this?, No!', 'D E F', 'G']
```

Answer (score 2):

for the RegEx solution:

you could either capture what you want like so

```
(".*?"|[^,]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/273)

or split on unquoted commas like so

```
,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/274)

Answer (score 1):

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/10